# retrieve and print property value of EL variables when property name contains a dot

Tags: jsp, el

I have a EL variable in my JSP as:
${USER_INFO}
If I print it's value in JSP, it displays as:

{address.locality=XYZ, given_name=john}

Now to get given_name attribute value from this, I can just do ${USER_INFO.given_name}

But, how I do get the value of address.locality?
${USER_INFO.address.locality} does not print any value

I do not have control over the attribute name address.locality to remove the dot there.
Is there some way I could retrieve and print the correct value of address.locality from this EL variable in that case?

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured the right way. It was pretty simple. I could just do 
${USER_INFO['address.locality']}